# Chrome's console.log prints incorrect var value

Tags: angular, google-chrome, console.log

I have two way binding for boolean values in an Angular application. In my component, I have declared the variable as follows

```
data = [
    {name:'xyz', value:'0', checked:false},
    {name:'abc', value:'1', checked:false},
    {name:'def', value:'2', checked:false}
];
```

In my HTML file I have following code:

```html
    <li *ngFor="let option of data">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   (click)="clicked($event)"
                   name="options"
                   value="{{option.value}}"
                   [(ngModel)]="option.checked" />
                {{option.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
```

The `clicked` function is given below:

```js
    clicked(event:any) {
        console.log(this.data);
        for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.data[i]);
        }
    }
```

I am facing a weird behaviour as `console.log(this.data)` is printing something different than the individual `console.log` I do for each option:

[image]

Can anyone tell what is going wrong.

Comment: `But the same when put in a for loop it prints as follows`. Not clear what you mean there. Where do you put that for-loop that doesn't work?

Comment: @MondKin, I think he means the `for(var i=0;i<this. data.length;i++){` loop in `clicked(event:any)` method

Comment: Oh got it. @Chandan are you using Chrome?

Comment: @MondKin Yes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome has an unexpected behaviour when it comes to the `console.log` function. When you do something like this:

```
console.log(this.data);
```

If `data` is too large, Chrome will collapse it, and will not print the current value at the moment the statement executes:

[image]

Chrome will resolve the `data` variable's value only when you click on the "expand" button. Notice that, when you expand your data, Chrome puts a blue info button next to it, if you hover it you'll see a message `"Value below was evaluated just now"` which means you are seeing the current value of the variable, not the value it had when you attempted to print it.

[image]

If you want to actually see the value a variable had when you attempted to print it you'll need to do this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
```

Which converts your data to a string as it was at the moment of evaluation, thus bypassing Chrome's "evaluated just now" mechanism:

[image]

Also, notice the `click` event happens before the setter of `ngModel`.
When the function `clicked` is executed none of your data has changed (all the `checked = false`) even for the first statement. But by the time you click on the expand icon, the setter of `ngModel` has already had time to execute, so you'll see the current value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what is the preferred way of getting checked values in this case?

Comment: If you want the pre-ngModel value? I'd put this in my componenet: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));`. If you want the post-ngModel value? I'd use `ngChange` or put this in my template: `{{ data }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little something I wrote that helps maintain sanity while trying to debug using console.log 
[image: synchronous console.log]

just do

```
import {betterConsole} from <path to betterConsole>
let console = betterConsole;
```

...now just use `console.log` like normal but the wrapper will be called instead. If you want to get the old, counter intuitive behaviour of `console.log`, just use `console.lie` (fair warning, I have not actually tested console.lie).

Answer (score 0):

```
affichage de deux attributs d'un tableau d'objet

Etat = [
        {  id: 1, name: 'Pression pneus', checked: false },
        {  id: 2, name: 'Direction', checked: false },
        {  id: 3, name: 'Eclairage', checked: false },
        {  id: 4, name: 'Kit anti-crevaison', checked: false }
    ];     

get  resultEtat() {
           return this.Etat.filter(item => item.checked).map(({id, name}) => { return {id, name}})
        };
```